# Spring Boot external configuration of multi-module project on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, tomcat9

I have multi-module Maven project with four Spring Boot 2.3.x applications as WAR files. I understand how to manage properties for each application for different profiles (dev, test, qa) when they run independently.

Now I deploy the applications on an external Tomcat 9.x server and I would like to have external property files for every single Spring Boot application.

The property files should be externalized outside Tomcat on the file system like this:

```
c:/webapp/spring-config/boot-app1-prod.properties
c:/webapp/spring-config/boot-app2-prod.properties
c:/webapp/spring-config/boot-app3-prod.properties
c:/webapp/spring-config/boot-app4-prod.properties
```

So for my understanding "spring.config.location" is not an option, because I can only specify the location and one property file per Tomcat instance.

I would like to externalize those files only for the active profile 'prod', so this is set:

```
spring.profiles.active=prod
```

**Question:**

What is best practice to achieve this?
Spring Cloud Config is not an option at this time.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder) {
    return springApplicationBuilder
            .sources(ExtpropApplication.class)
            .properties(getProperties());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(ExtpropApplication.class)
    .sources(ExtpropApplication.class)
    .properties(getProperties())
    .run(args);
}
```

> You can add more then one files using spring.config.name, use the profile conditions before read the file(I didn't add those line on code, based on your preference you can add.)

```
static Properties getProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("spring.config.name","boot-app1-prod.properties,boot-app2-prod.properties,boot-app3-prod.properties,boot-app4-prod.properties");
    props.put("spring.config.location", "file://"+configPath());
    return props;
}
```

> If the path will read dynamic and out of war file use the following method to read the files.

```
public static String configPath() {
    File file = new File("."); 
    String path=file.getAbsolutePath();
    int secondLast = path.length()-2;
    String destinationPath = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/",secondLast)+1);
    String resourcePath=destinationPath+"/webapps/";
    return resourcePath;

}
```

> This is for war deployment and properties location will be dynamic, incase it is static path we can achieve on annotation itself.